MySQL query outs values with join for a specific condition
I have a MySQL table that used to manage meter reading, issue qty and issue dates of fuel. Sample data are as follows:



vehicle
reading
qty
date




11
12000
12
2024-08-01


11
6000
8
2024-08-12


12
15000
15
2024-08-05


12
19000
10
2024-08-08


11
11000
12
2024-08-08



I want to get a summary that shows the running KMS by calculating the used number of KMs using issued fuel. last & most immediate reading is used for the calculation and should be grouped by vehicle. Expected result is as follows :



vehicle
no_of_kms




11
5000


12
4000



I used the following query
(select MAX(d1.reading)-MIN(d1.reading) FROM tbl_direct_fuel t1

LEFT JOIN tbl_direct_fuel t2 ON t1.vehicle = t2.vehicle
group by vehicle) no_of_kms
Output
But the query outs an empty result. I can't find the bug in my query. Can anyone help ?

d1.date < d1.date will never be true. You're comparing the column with itself in the same row, they must be equal.

If you want to compare a row with the preceding row, use the LAG() window function.

You also need GROUP BY vehicle to get per-vehicle results.

@
Barmar. Yes. If I remove that, the code outs same value for all vehicles

Why are you joining with tbl_vehicle? You never use anything from that table.

That's because you forgot GROUP BY, so you're processing the entire table, not each vehicle. This is SQL 101.

"But the query out an empty result".  d1.date < d1.date is like putting a condition 1 < 1.  It will never ever be true.  There will never be a record returned.

MAX(d1.reading)-MIN(d1.reading).  Your MAX will return 19000 and your MIN will return 6000

@ Eric. Yes. 19000 for vehicle 12 & 6000 for vehicle 11. I want to get the difference of last readings for the same vehicle. Then group by vehicle by comparing different vehicles.

@ Eric. I edit the question as per your suggestion.
